# How to get video id of the successfully uploaded youtube video?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am uploading video to youtube by using their API. After the successful upload, i want to get the video id which i am unable to find. I have found this in the video_entry object as id.

```
    <ns0:id xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/nK1Ax6320T8</ns0:id>
```

Here, nK1Ax6320T8 is the video id. How can i parse it in python. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse that url parameters, Python provides a [good library](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) to do that.

There's [good sample code](https://code.google.com/p/hello-youtube/source/browse/trunk/06_hello_browser_based_upload/main.py) from the YouTube data API docs that does exactly what you're asking about. Checkout [line 76](https://code.google.com/p/hello-youtube/source/browse/trunk/06_hello_browser_based_upload/main.py#76).